# Self Updating app?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and I would like to ask if a self-updating feature could be possible. The details are:

1. The application is designed as an In House App, not going to be published on Google Play.
2. Will need to run only in Kiosk mode.
3. The self-updating feature will have to work as following: In the settings screen, there will be an Update button that will start downloading the new version of apk. After the apk will be downloaded, it will have to start the updating process automatically.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, but the downloaded apk installation must be accepted by the end user, so it is not a fully automatic process. Why is publishing to the Play Store not an option? Play Store updates are automatic, and your end users would also trust you a little bit more. I wouldn't download an APK from the web if I'm not 100% sure it is a safe one. Also, a lot of phones disable installing downloaded APKs by default.

Comment: @BackSlash As OP mentions that the app is going to be only for internal use. They don't want the world to be aware that such app exists or they can download it. And for the trust issue, since it's for internal use, they would definitely trust the APKs downloaded from their own trusted server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, furthermore, there are services that can do this for you, such as [HockeyApp's update manager](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#updatedistribution-advanced)